# Cloudfront - how to propagate signed url to all website requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using CloudFront to privately access an S3 Bucket enabled as a website.

So I turned on `Restrict Viewer Access` with a previously created `Trusted Key Group`.

Now, when I create a signed cloudfront url via AWS CLI, for example :

```
http://...cloudfront.net/?Expires=...&Signature=...Key-Pair-Id=...
```

It only works for the first request of my website (index.html) since that's the one that has the query strings, but any subsequent request (any javascript, images) it simply returns `index.html`, probably because those don't get the signed headers.

Is there a way to fix this? I'm not sure if it's something I configure in the browser or in the `index.html` headers or something in CloudFront, maybe a lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is quite weird, as S3 bucket enabled as website requires files like HTML, JS, CSS, images, etc... to be made public for your website to run properly.

The error you encountered is expected, since you only signed the index.html file in your S3 bucket. The rest of other resources files required to render your website like javascript, images, css are not signed. Therefore, your site is not rendered properly.

A Cloudfront signed URL is specifically tied to the file in your S3 bucket, you cannot reuse the signed query params or cookies to access other files.

My suggestion is, if you are hosting a website in S3, make the bucket public and don't use Cloudfront signed URL.

For private contents, you can put them in other buckets and use Cloudfront signed URL to access them separately.

Alternatively, if you don't want to make the whole bucket public, you can make individual files public.

Ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html